# Network File Transfer Failures using Windows 7 Client and Windows CE "server"

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, server-message-block, corruption, windows-ce

Our company has 3 printers from Solidscape, each of which are controlled by a directly attached Windows CE device.  This device exposes a file share via SMB which can be used to drop print jobs to be started from the device's graphical interface.

When using Windows XP, transferring to this machine results in an exact duplicate and an error free print job.

When using Windows 7, the normal file copy dialog appears and disappears correctly after transferring the file.  The share reports back to Windows Explorer that the file arrived and was allocated the correct volume of data, but running an md5sum on the original file and its counterpart across the network results in two different hashes.  Also, the address bar of the Windows Explorer used as the target of this copy operation displays the embedded progress bar through about 60% quickly.  It then slows to a crawl around 85-90% and doesn't finish at all (at least for the 10 minutes I waited for a 900KB file).

I know Windows 7 has interoperability problems, by default, with older clients.  What am I missing?  Should a registry fix be in order?  Has anyone else had issues with Windows CE and file sharing?

Note: I cannot eliminate Windows CE from the equation as this is provided by Solidscape to drive the printers.